# Grid hub and node - Unable to register the node in different machine

Tags: selenium-grid

I am trying to install Selenium Grid - hub in one machine(windows 10) and node(windows 8.1 physical device) in different machine. I am able to successfully register the hub, but stuck in node registering. I used java -jar C:\selenium-server-standalone-3.0.0.jar -role  node -hub http://192.168.56.1:4444/grid/register -port 5555. Getting error: couldnt register the node: the hub is down or not responding. I tried webdriver instead of node, still no luck. Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Have you started a hub first?

Comment: Yes, started the hub using  java -jar C:\selenium\selenium-server-standalone-3.0.0.jar -port 5555 -role hub

Comment: It seems hub is not started properly. Try to start on port 4444 or 4445